# How to provide mapping info in bundle but allow Entity class to be overriden

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been developing applications in Symfony for a couple years now but haven't yet done a deep dive into independent bundle development, and it's biting me in the butt at the moment.

What I'm trying to do is provide some pre-defined entities which consuming applications can install but then override with their own entity classes if needs be.

Here are the two tables I'm providing with my bundle

**src/My/CustomBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="My\CustomBundle\Entity\User" table="user">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="16" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="255" nullable="true"/>
    <one-to-many field="properties" target-entity="My\CustomBundle\Entity\UserProperty" mapped-by="user" fetch="EAGER" />
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**src/My/CustomBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="My\CustomBundle\Entity\UserProperty" table="user_property">
    <indexes>
      <index name="fk_user_property_user1_idx" columns="user_id"/>
    </indexes>
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint columns="user_id,key" name="user_key_UNIQUE" />
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="key" type="string" column="`key`" length="45" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="value" type="string" column="`value`" length="255" nullable="true"/>
    <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="My\CustomBundle\Entity\User" inversed-by="properties">
      <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I just used the tools to auto-generate Entity classes from these mappings, so I won't bother posting the code for those because they're very predictable.

The problem then comes when I try to use these entities from another bundle.  For example.

**src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use My\CustomBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser {}
```

Now this always prompts the error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                           
  Class "AppBundle\Entity\User" sub class of "My\CustomBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

If I try to inform doctrine that `AppBundle\Entity\User` is an entity, like so

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use My\CustomBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser {}
```

Then this also fails

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]              
  The table with name 'database.user' already exists.
```

Is there a sane way for a bundle to provide pre-mapped entites but also allow for the consuming application to override them as needed?

Version Info

- PHP 5.4.16
- Symfony 2.6.4
- Doctrine (Common) 2.4.2

Comment: I dont know the best/preferred strategy off hand but I know FOSUserBundle uses mapped super classes like `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`. But they may be doing something special in their `UserManager` in order to get everything to work properly. Not 100% on this. Its been awhile since I've used it.

Comment: I kinda poked through their implementation and unfortunately, I can't use mapped-superclasses because they don't let you define both sides of a one-to-many relationship

Comment: You can configure the mapping portion of the doctrine configuration such that your BaseBundle is skipped.  The will get you past the user table already exists problem.  Of course that means you have to create new entity classes for all the entities and copy over their mapping.  Try your best to adjust your design to use mapped super classes.  Or maybe instead of extending the base classes you could setup a 1:1 relation with the custom classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using doctrine, you need to either use single table inheritance, or a mapped supperclass.

here are the reference docs:

[Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

[Mapped Superlcass](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)

Note that doctrine has other types of inheritance, but they don't exactly apply to this use case.  They are:

[Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

[Overrides](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides)

If your use case doesn't fall into one of those categories you basically need to create your own entity from scratch and handle all the associations, mappings, etc on your own.

Comment: I ended up modifying my design and updating the documentation in the bundle to indicate that if consumers wish to use custom entities, they'll need to regenerate all the mapping.  Thanks!